# How to build MySql static library with Visual C++ and system zlib library?

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, build, cmake, nmake

I build MySql client static library on Windows with NMake. The file `mysqlclient.lib` for any reason embedds `zlib.lib`, so when I link application that uses `zlib.lib` togeather with `mysqlclient.lib`, I receive following link error:

`inflateSync already defined in mysqlclient.lib`

And many similar ones. I set option `WITH_ZLIB:STRING=system`, however, it looks like MySql build system completely ignores this option.

How to build MySql static library with Visual C++ without embedded zlib library? Is there any way better than manual rewritting of make file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only solution I found is to build library "as is" and use `lib /REMOVE` to remove object files related to `zlib` from `mysqlclient.lib`. When done, the library compiles well togeather with `zlib`. `CMake` on Windows searches `zlib` at some fixed locations with fixed filenames, and any change in `zlib` file name makes it impossible for `CMake` to recognize the library.